# How do you do your dynamic layouts?

Tags: android

I want to dynamically hide/show controls in an activity based on a button touch event: when the user presses the "details" button, I want to show more controls in the same activity.

What is the best way to handle this?  Is there a way to do `TextView.Hide()`? Can it animate the transition?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`setVisibility()` will allow you to make a widget visible, invisible, or gone. The difference between the latter two is that an invisible widget still takes up space, while a widget that is gone does not.

Android has an entire [animation framework](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-descr.html) for slides, fades, spins, and the like. [Here are two sample projects](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Animation/) showing some of this.

Comment: Thanks
This seems to be exactly what I was looking for.